# Excel DNA - Get retrieving values from cells via an ExcelReference

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I have a function that I am passing a range of values, what is the best way to retrieve the values using the ExcelReference

```
public static object TestRange([ExcelArgument(AllowReference = true)] 
   object valueRange)
        {
            ExcelReference valueRangeRef = (ExcelReference)valueRange;
            int rowFirst = valueRangeRef.RowFirst;
            int rowLast = valueRangeRef.RowLast;
            int colFirst = valueRangeRef.ColumnFirst;
            int colLast = valueRangeRef.ColumnLast;

            for (int i = colFirst; i < colLast; i++)
            {
                for (int j = rowFirst; j < rowFirst; j++)
                {
                    //var value = ??
                }
            }

            return "Done";
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get the values is to mark your parameter as `AllowReference=false` - then you'll get an `object[,]` array with the values directly.

You can iterate through the values like this:

```
public static object Concat2(object[,] values)
{
    string result = "";
    int rows = values.GetLength(0);
    int cols = values.GetLength(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            object value = values[i, j];
            result += value.ToString();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you do need to work with an `ExcelReference`, you can get the contents with a call to `GetValue()` which returns the same `object[,]`.